# How to create a terminal output viewer in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bash, vue.js

I need to figure out a way to show the output of a particular bash command (like `ls -la`) in my web application and I wanted to know if there is a library that does that. Simply showing the output in the black/white style is not enough since the output contains characters that only a bash terminal can render in the right way. For example, the output of `composer install` contains the following line (the percentage is changing):

```
  - Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.4): Downloading (100%)
```

but behind the terminal, it has the following appearance:

```
  - Installing bacon/bacon-qr-code (2.0.4): Downloading (connecting...)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (0%)           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (5%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (10%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (15%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (45%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (50%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (55%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (60%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (65%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (70%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (75%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (80%)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bDownloading (100%)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you getting the data to be displayed by the terminal viewer?

Comment: I run the commands on the back-end side and then transfer the output line after line through a socket to the front-end side

Comment: I am doing something like that now too. After searching around I decided the best option is to build the output viewer myself and use a specific in-browser implementation to transcribe data like (composer install) to be displayed on the client side. The Fiddle for the viewer(just started working on it): https://jsfiddle.net/seriously_/03t1nucL/#&togetherjs=LyaQcADj0x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is Xterm.js (https://xtermjs.org/). All the major Web apps (or even desktop ones based on Electron) are using it for emulating console/terminal look and behavior. And it's frameworks agnostic, meaning that you can use it with whatever framework or library you like.

I don't know of any other better for what you seek to achieve.